# OmniAuth Facebook expired token error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, rubygems, omniauth

I am using OmniAuth to get access to Facebook in my app. I am using the fb_graph gem: https://github.com/nov/fb_graph to post to Facebook. I am running omniauth-0.3.0 on Heroku for this app. The token that I save when the user is created is changed when the user logs in sometime later.

Code for creating user

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController  
    def create  
     auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]  
     user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])||           
     User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
       session[:user_id] = user.id  
       redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"  
         end
```

The User model is:

```
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)  
    create! do |user|  
    user.provider = auth["provider"]  
    user.uid = auth["uid"]  
    user.name = auth["user_info"]["name"] 
    user.token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
    end
   end
```

I am now seeing this error on about 30% users-

```
 FbGraph::InvalidToken (OAuthException :: Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.)
```

I saw that the expired token issue has been recently fixed in OmniAuth:

https://github.com/soopa/omniauth/commit/67bdea962e3b601b8ee70e21aedf5e6ce1c2b780

I used this code which tries to refresh the access token. However, I still get the same error. Can someone point to what I am missing? **Is there some other way I could update the token every time the user logs in?**

**The only solution which has worked is to create a new User everytime the User logs in** (I don't like this solution at all):

```
  def create  
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"] 
    user = User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id  
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"  
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply update the token when you create the session.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController  
def create  
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]  
  user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]).tap do |u|
           u.update_attributes(:token => auth["credentials"]["token"]) if u
         end || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  session[:user_id] = user.id  
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"  
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had one question - I am using FB login using omniauth. The FB token changes from time-to-time so the token could change while user is using application long after logging in. To encounter this, right now I am using "offline_access" permission so that FB generates long-lived tokens. Is there a way I could solve this issue without "offline_access". It would probably need my application to ask for renewed token via omniauth before posting to Facebook (anytime after logging in). Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: In my experience, the only time the token has changed with 'offline_access' set is when the user changes their password on Facebook.  Other than that, the tokens have remained the same for over a year.  When the password changes, they have to login again to get the new token, as per above.

Comment: I agree with what you say. With "offline_access" set the token has not changed. However, I was wondering how I can handle it without "offline_access" set? ("offline_access" is an additional permission from user so likely to introduce some friction from some users who might not want app to "Access their data any time")

Comment: I saw this change to omniauth which tries to refresh expired tokens - https://github.com/soopa/omniauth/commit/67bdea962e3b601b8ee70e21aedf5e6ce1c2b780 . I am not sure how to use it in my code though.

Comment: New URL for link in previous comment: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/commit/67bdea962e3b601b8ee70e21aedf5e6ce1c2b780

Comment: Anyone knows how to use the commit mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

I was using similar solution before you answered this question-

```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController  
  def create  
 auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]  
 user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) ||  User.create_with_omniauth(auth)  

 user.update_attributes(:token => auth["credentials"]["token"])

 session[:user_id] = user.id  
 redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"  

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't we refresh the token using FBGraph gem with follwing method in such case?

```
auth = FbGraph::Auth.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
auth.exchange_token! access_token # Needs fb_graph 2.3.1+
auth.access_token # => new token
```

However, This will not extend token's expiry but will replace token with new one. Expiry time will remain same. Checked it with FB, They may not allow to extend FB token expiry more than 60 days.
Maximum token validity is 60-days.

reference: https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/wiki/Authentication#wiki-extend-token-expiry